# ActiveSheet.Paste Error on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets (Input & Record), I just want to copy some data from "Input" to "Record", it worked but if I protect "Record".... **Paste method of Worksheet class Failed** comes up.
So I added script for unprotected sheets and protect sheets, but '1004' stil comes up.
Here the detail of my project.

- **Input** sheet is area for me to input some value to a row. In 1 row at least have 10 values at different column.
- Maximum row that I can add is ten rows.
- **Record** sheet is database as **Table1** based on how much row from **Input** sheet that i'll add.

Here my script

```
Sub adddata() 'this sub code from button on "Input" sheet

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("C15").Offset(1, 0).Select 'select range start from C16
If Range("M27") = 1 Then 'value for how much row that i'll add
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Else
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End If
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Record").Select
Worksheets("Record").Unprotect Password:="4321"
If Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
    Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
    ActiveSheet.Paste '<< The trouble maker
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

That I want to know:

1. What I've missed?
2. The solution of this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all this `Select` process is not necessary and you can avoid that. I can edit my answer if you will add your intentions "what you are trying to do".

You want to copy some range from `Input` and paste it to `Record` always to the next empty row?

If I understood you correct, maybe something like this?

```
Sub adddata()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Unprotect Password:="4321"
    
    Dim NextFreeCell As Range
    Set NextFreeCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
        If .Range("B2").Value = 1 Then
            .Range("C15", .Range("C15").End(xlToRight)).Copy
        Else
            .Range("C15", .Range("C15").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
        End If
    End With
    
    NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Here is how it works:

[image]

---

This was not included in your original question. So you have to create a new question with additional information to your original question. However this time I will answer here but not next time.

Here is the code for table:

```
Sub adddata()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Unprotect Password:="4321"
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
            If .Range("B2").Value = 1 Then
                .Range("C15", .Range("C15").End(xlToRight)).Copy
            Else
                .Range("C15", .Range("C15").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
            End If
        End With
        
        .Range.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Remove all empty cells in table below your last data. This code will add a new line to table. Also table name should correspond to your table name. Can be found in Excel under `Format Table`

[image]

Comment: Sheet "Input" is area for me to input some values into a row & 1 row have at least 10 values at different column based on how much I input the values.
Maximum row that i add input is 10 rows.

Sheet "Record" is database based on sheet "Input".
At the first time Record must be empty, but it will increase with time.

My code is try to copy on each row from "Input" to "Record", that's why i put "M27" for how much row to copy and I add looping code for that.

Comment: @user14036929 I have edited my answer. It should work now as expected.

Comment: Sorry, This sub code is come from button that I put on "Input" sheets and in my code, B2 is on "Record" Sheet.
I'll edit my question more specific.

Comment: @user14036929 what is the problem with button? I have added gif, you can see how it works. There is no difference in code is it button or not.

Comment: I'm sorry @Tabisamsa, there's no problem with button, i just too early conclude your code.
It actually works, but your code make the value paste to the bottom in "Record" sheet.
..and again, i think i forget to tell you, that database on "Record" sheet is a **table**

Comment: @user14036929 where it should paste then? Maybe it is better to ask another question, describing where it should paste with screenshot of Record sheet.

Comment: Based on your code, the value put in here <img src="https://imgur.com/R2Ag1dh"> it should be placed in here <img src="https://imgur.com/Kp04NpK">

Comment: I'm so sorry about my bad question @Tabisamsa, btw it works, no error comes up again, but the problem is >> https://imgur.com/b9C0Wlh
Add a new line on the Table1, but there aren't values in that line. It's okay, I'll find out by my self, the only problem is when i try to add some values in a new line on "Record" **Paste method of Worksheet class Failed** always comes up.
Now I understand why, It because I used .Paste method on **Sheets** instead of .PasteSpecial method on **Cell**.

Comment: @Jek you have to check your data, Table name and other parameters on your Workbook and edit code to correspond your values.. See new gif added, everything works. Also I would not do it with using Select. You can read some posts on this website about why it is not good to use Select.

Comment: @Jek also remove all empty rows in your table first. My code is adding them itself. Select rows 17, 18 -> and click delete. There is no need to have empty rows in your table for upcoming data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub adddata()

Worksheets("Record").Unprotect Password:="4321" ' Unlock the target sheet before copying.

Sheets("Input").Select
Range("C15").Offset(1, 0).Select
If Range("M27") = 1 Then
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Else
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End If
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Record").Select
If Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
    Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
    Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
    Activecell.PasteSpecial xlAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Record").Protect Password:="4321", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but comes another error, "PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed"

Comment: I'm sorry I used activesheet instead of activecell. I have corrected my answer.